# How to run Privilege Exec command in Ansible on Cisco Router

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to write a playbook to perform a packet capture. The commands are run in Privilege exec mode, i.e #   Not config mode (config#) and not user exec (>)

I have to run become and become_method: enable so that I can get into the device. However when I run the playbook with become and become_method I get `\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\nrouter(config)#\n`".

When I run the playbook without become and become_method I get the "operation requires privilege escalation\n"

The commands in question:

```
  - name: setup packet capture
    ios_config:
      lines:
        - monitor capture buffer PKT size 2048 max-size 4096 circular
        - monitor capture buffer PKT filter access-list PackCap
    become: yes
    become_method: enable
```

How do I run the command in just privilege exec mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want [`ios_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/ios_command_module.html), since as best I can tell `monitor capture` is not a _config_ setting

Comment: Yep, the error for ios_command is:  FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ios_command) module: lines Supported parameters include: auth_pass, authorize, commands, host, interval, match, password, port, provider, retries, ssh_keyfile, timeout, username, wait_for"}

Comment: I believe the docs say to use `commands:` instead of `lines:`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel your comment was the solution, thanks! I had thought that "lines" and "commands" were interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use [ios_command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/ios_command_module.html), since `monitor capture` is not a config setting

Also be careful to use `commands:` instead of `lines:`